# Accessing the wallet with the keystore generated using myetherwallet.com

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I assume the UTC file which got generated in myetherwallet is the keystore file. Also I have my private key noted.

I understand that the myetherwallet will stay long and there is no plan to close in near future.

Could you please let me know how to use the keystore file or private key and access my wallet without using myetherwallet ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions depending on what you want to use instead of myetherwallet. A standard one would be to use geth and mist.

Once you will have geth installed, there should be an ethereum folder somewhere on your computer. On linux, it is probably `~/.ethereum`. For geth to find your keys, you must copy them in the `.ethereum/keystore/` folder.

Then geth and mist (using geth) should be able to use your keys.

It is **a good practice for you to copy your myetherwallet `keystore/` folder on at least one device you own** (even without installing geth): then if anything happens to the website (like a DOS attack) you still can spend them by installing geth or any other ethereum client.

Comment: Can I replace the UTC file in Mist .. Ethereum->keystore with the one from myetherwallet.com and use it flawlessly ?

Comment: If there is an UTC file in the keystore it means that you have a private key on which you could own ether. Do not remove it. You can have any number of UTC files in your keystore, so just copy the other one in it.

Comment: Ok.. The utc file is encrypted.. Where it will ask for password